# Issues with getting JSON data from AJAX POST

Tags: python, ajax

The AJAX call looks like this:

```
        json_dictionary = {url : url, profile_dict: dictionary, final_dict : final_dictionary}
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://localhost:8090/add_profile_data",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(json_dictionary),
            contentType:'application/json',
            success:function() {
                console.log('added profile data')
            }
        })
```

The client side looks like this:

```
@app.route('/add_profile_data', methods=['POST', 'GET', 'OPTIONS'])
def add():
    data = request.json
    print(type(data))
```

That works, and the result from print is `<type 'dict'>`

Also, when I print the `data` object, everything is there.

However, when I try:

```
@app.route('/add_profile_data', methods=['POST', 'GET', 'OPTIONS'])
def add():
    data = request.json
    print(data.keys())
```

I get an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'`

I don't understand why this is happening? Any thoughts?

Update:

Changed the server to this, and now seeing `NoneType` for `print(type(data))`
Server:

```
@app.route('/add_profile_data', methods=['POST', 'GET', 'OPTIONS'])
def add():
    data = request.json
    print(type(data))
    print(data.keys())
```

Response:

```
<type 'NoneType'>
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2017 09:13:47] "OPTIONS /add_profile_data HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2000, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1567, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/morganallen/Dropbox/Coding_Projects/Prediction_Server/prediction_v2.py", line 172, in add
    print(data.keys())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Any reason why I am seeing `NoneType`?

Comment: Sorry but I really have a hard time believing this... You could print `type(data)` and then in the same call try to print the keys. Maybe something changed in between...

Comment: Are you sure that you are handling a POST request when the error happens?  Your route is for GET, POST or OPTIONS, but probably only POST will include json.

Comment: Huh, you are right Jean-Francois...something did change. Updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2017 09:13:47] "OPTIONS /add_profile_data HTTP/1.1" 500`

An `OPTIONS` request will not include JSON.

Edit your code to only check the JSON if the method is `POST`.

For example:

```
@app.route('/add_profile_data', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.json
        print(type(data))
        print(data.keys())
```

Comment: Can you make a suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: Ahh, ok, I took out "options" from the methods and it worked as expected.

Comment: can you edit this answer and remove "options" from methods so it is accurate?